# Invalid unicode character in xml attribute / tag

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8

What are the list of invalid unicode characters in xml attributes (tags)?

As the following python3 code illustrates:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO as sio

xml_dec = '<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
unicode_text = '<root>textº</root>'
valid_unicode = '<标签 属性="值">文字</标签>'
invalid_unicode_attribute = '<tag attributeº="value">text</tag>'
invalid_unicode_tag = '<tagº>text</tagº>'

ET.parse(sio(xml_dec + unicode_text))
# works

ET.parse(sio(xml_dec + valid_unicode))
# works

ET.parse(sio(xml_dec + invalid_unicode_attribute))
# ParseError

ET.parse(sio(xml_dec + invalid_unicode_tag))
# ParseError
```

The unicode character `º`, i.e. `U+00BA`, can be parsed if it is in the element text, but not in element attribute or tag. On the other hand, other unicode characters, such as Chinese characters, can be parsed in element attribute and tag.

I checked the xml `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?><tagº>text</tagº>` in https://validator.w3.org/check, and it gives the error:

> Line 1, Column 43: character "º" not allowed in attribute
>   specification list

However, in [XML Recommendation 1.1, §2.2 Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets), it says it is allowed:

> Char     ::=      [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */

My question is, where can I find the list of invalid unicode characters in XML attributes / tags?

Comment: Is this about attributes now or tag names? The title and the last sentence talk about attributes, but the examples are about text and tags only.

Comment: In any case, you just need to scroll a bit in the document you linked yourself. For example, [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-NameStartChar) is the definition of which characters you may use in a tag name.

Comment: You would find it easier to get answers to such questions if you mastered the terminology. Here's an example of a tag: `<a href='a.xml'/>`. It contains two names (an element name and an attribute name) and various other stuff including an attribute value, spaces, an equals sign, apostrophes etc. I think your question is not about what characters are allowed in the tag, but about what characters are allowed in the element name and attribute name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For characters allowed in tag and attribute names, the [W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/) (to which you linked yourself – but you were looking at the definition of what can be used in a text node) states the following:

> Almost all characters are permitted in names, except those which either are or reasonably could be used as delimiters.

and

> Document authors are encouraged to use names which are meaningful words or combinations of words in natural languages, and to avoid symbolic or white space characters in names. Note that COLON, HYPHEN-MINUS, FULL STOP (period), LOW LINE (underscore), and MIDDLE DOT are explicitly permitted.
>
> The ASCII symbols and punctuation marks, along with a fairly large group of Unicode symbol characters, are excluded from names because they are more useful as delimiters in contexts where XML names are used outside XML documents; providing this group gives those contexts hard guarantees about what cannot be part of an XML name.

This is followed by a [formal definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-NameStartChar) which lists a lot of Unicode ranges:

```
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
                  [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
                  [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
                  [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
                  [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 |
                  [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

The *masculine ordinal indicator* `º` (`#xBA`) is not among them, for whatever reason (at least, some languages use it in abbreviations for common words, so it doesn't look like a “delimiter” to me).

It's also interesting to see that you can use digits, hyphens and periods in tag names, but not as the first character.